# std::map insert && overload causes copy

Tags: c++, stl, stdmap, value-categories

Looking at this interesting talk:

[CppCon 2017: Matt Kulukundis “Designing a Fast, Efficient, Cache-friendly Hash Table, Step by Step”](https://youtu.be/ncHmEUmJZf4?list=RDYA-nB2wjVcI&t=2302)

He mentions around minute 38:32 that

```
void Benchmark_Slow(int iters) {
    std::unordered_map<string, int> m;
    std::pair<const string, int> p = {};
    while (iters--) m.insert(p)
}
```

is ~2x slower than the following variation

```
void Benchmark_Fast(int iters) {
    std::unordered_map<string, int> m;
    const std::pair<const string, int> p = {};
    while (iters--) m.insert(p)
}
```

I am still thinking about why the `&&` overload (1) would be selected.

- `std::pair<iterator,bool> insert( value_type&& value ); (1)`
- `std::pair<iterator,bool> insert( const value_type& value ); (3)`

where `value_type`is `std::pair<const Key, T>`.

After all, we are not moving the values, so in my understanding, the expression `p` should be an lvalue and not an x/prvalue, is that right? Can somebody enlighten me?

Comment: What is `_const_` an alias for in this context? Just `const`?

Comment: [Benchmarks](http://quick-bench.com/xqzq00E_KLdpBNSoJAyHupp7dKg)

Comment: @Xirema I'm gonna assume it's an alias for OP trying to put markdown inside of a code block. revert if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't take the problematic overloads:

```
std::pair<iterator,bool> insert(const value_type& value); // (1)

template< class P >
std::pair<iterator,bool> insert(P&& value); // (2)
```

`P` deduced as `value_type&`.

Comment: For what reason is there an overload taking a template parameter? I feel like I am missing something trivial, but nothing comes to my mind. Would you mind providing some source on that or, in the case of trivial answer, provide it yourself?

Comment: Sorry, I don't have the rational, the one taking `value_type&&` has been added afterward (in C++17). forwarding references was young...

Comment: Why does the forwarding reference overload cause an extra copy to be made?  It seems like a reference to the original object should be passed along to `value_type`'s constructor, same as the const-reference overload.

Comment: 2nd overload would use `emplace` instead, which seems to be slower (also covered by your linked video) (remember that key is already present, so created node is immediately destroyed, whereas `insert` can check presence before creation).

Comment: A map's `value_type` is `pair<const Key, Value>`, so you don't want to force an early conversion to a `value_type` temporary because then you can't move from the key, hence the templated insert. This is just a missed optimization on the implementation's part though.

Comment: I somehow missed the point, that the map is constantly trying to insert the same key. Now it makes sense, many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

1. The template overload is called ([overload (2) on cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/insert))
2. The template overload is equivalent to `emplace`
3. `emplace` is not slower that `insert` and is faster in general case, but...

But, `emplace` allows for one abuse and that is when you repeatedly try to insert the same key. And the benchmark does exactly that (note that `while`). I'd say it's just a benchmark that show a behavior when you are deliberately shooting yourself in the foot. In the real world i don't think one would do that via `emplace` or `insert`.

In C++17 this has been fixed in 1 way that requires to modify your code:

1. `try_emplace` function https://isocpp.org/files/papers/n4279.html

Comment: C++17 adds overload taking `value_type&&`, I don't see overload taking `value_type&` (which is what it is passed).